# How to test components with dynamic imports in vue-test-utils and jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, importerror, vue-test-utils

I am testing a component which dynamically imports the child components. Here a screenshot of that section

Inside Parent.vue

[image: Inside Parent.vue]

Error

[image]

It works fine for normal imports but not with dynamic async import. Can anyone help on how configure Jest to support async component imports?

Answer (score 4):

If problem is still relevant (I didn't found anydirect answer) try to 'stub' components which should be imported.

Component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <dynamic-imported-component-one id="componentOne"></dynamic-imported-component-one>
        <dynamic-imported-component-two id="componentTwo"></dynamic-imported-component-two>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    const ComponentOne = resolve => import(/* webpackChunkName: "views/view-ComponentOne-vue" */ '../Components/ComponentOne.vue');
    const ComponentTwo = resolve => import(/* webpackChunkName: "views/view-ComponentTwo-vue" */ '../Components/ComponentTwo.vue');

    export default {
        components: {
            'dynamicImportedComponentOne': ComponentOne,
            'dynamicImportedComponentTwo': ComponentTwo }
    }
</script>
```

Test:

```
describe('SomeComponent.vue', () => {

    const stubs = {
        dynamicImportedComponentOne: '<h3>Stubbed component one</h3>',
        dynamicImportedComponentTwo: '<h3>Stubbed component one</h3>'
    }

    it('test for SomeComponent', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(SomeComponent, { stubs });

        expect(wrapper.find('#componentOne').exists()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('#componentTwo').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

You can't test the ComponentOne/ComponentTwo content, but it should be anyway done in separate tests.

Comment: shallowMount automatically stubs all child component, I'm not sure if this approach helps in any way. I'm still getting the same error after trying to shallowMount and explicitly add the stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `"dynamic-import-node"` in you .babelrc ? It seemed to fix dynamic import of child components in a mounted parent for me. I got the pointer from https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1460#issuecomment-355193587 [image]